# How to set the publisher name in a BHO

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I have written a BHO and a toolbar for Internet Explorer in C#. They are getting installed and working properly. In the manage add-ons window in IE8, I am able to see both my BHO and toolbar. But, the publisher name of both is set to "Control name is not available". How can I set the publisher name?

Comment: Please don't put "C#" in the title. You have it in the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Are you signing your .dll?  You need to sign your modules as well as your installation package.
2. Make sure your .dll has a VERSIONINFO resource in your .rc file.  [Here's the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(VS.85).aspx) which has a sample you can basically cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Signed your Dll. assemblyinfo file in .net the attribute [assembly: AssemblyCompany("add Publisher Name Here ")] GOES as publisher name in a BHO..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After set following info in AssemblyInfo.cs file build the DLL.

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Your publisher name")]
```

When you register that DLL then use the following command.

```
regasm /register /codebase YourDLL.dll
```

Now it will show your publisher name in manage addon in IE.

Hope this make more sense.