# BHO is listed with "unknown publisher" in add-on list in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com

I have a browser helper object (BHO), written in C#. There are two files BHO32.dll and BHO64.dll. I signed both DLLs with a self-signed certificate. I have added this certificate to the windows certificate store. Both files were registered with regasm.exe and added to the global assembly cache (GAC). In the AssemblyInfo.cs file the "[assembly: [...]]" values were setted. But the manage add-on window in IE shows "unknown publisher".

Did I forget anything?

I also tried [How to set the publisher name in a BHO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763800/how-to-set-the-publisher-name-in-a-bho). But I get the error "CSC : error CS1583: [...]" by setting a resource file.

Comment: What does the windows explorer properties dialog show for the dll BHO files? Is the Publisher field complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering the DLL with `regasm.exe /codebase BHO32.dll` worked for me.
The name defined in `[assembly: AssemblyCompany("[...]")]` is shown in the manage add-on window in IE.

The company name is also shown, if the DLL is not signed. Then `(not verified)` is added to the company name in the addon list. After signing the DLL (with a valid certificate), only the company name is shown.

Answer (score 0):

here is the version info block from the googletoolbar.dll

1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 7,5,8231,2252
PRODUCTVERSION 7,5,8231,2252
FILEOS 0x40004
FILETYPE 0x2
{
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
{
    BLOCK "040904b0"
    {
        VALUE "CompanyName", "Google Inc."
        VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © 2000-2014"
        VALUE "FileDescription", "Google Toolbar"
        VALUE "ProductName", "Google Toolbar for Internet Explorer"
        VALUE "ProductVersion", "7, 5, 8231, 2252 "
        VALUE "FileVersion", "7, 5, 8231, 2252 "
        VALUE "OriginalFilename", "GoogleToolbar.dll"
        VALUE "InternalName", "GoogleToolbar"
    }
}

BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
{
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0409 0x04B0
}
}

Comment: I have copied and adjusted this block for my BHO in a rc file. I compiled this file with the RC.exe to get a res file. In my Visual Studio BHO project, under properties, I set this res file. So there is no error anymore. But the publisher is still not shown in IE addon list. My BHO consists of two DLLs. One 32bit and one 64bit.

Comment: I've had the same problem with resource dll only extensions. I have not found a work-around to get the publisher to be listed in the Addons manager... 32 bit resource.dll extensions will work on both x86 and x64 bit versions of IE/windows.

Answer (score 0):

Resource.dll extensions for IE - The publisher specified in the RC block does not appear in the IE Addons Manager listing.

[image: My Addons manager listing of Command bar/Tools extensions (resource dlls]

The publisher does appear in the Programs and Features applet though

[image]

I don't think there is a workaround...